# How to generate unique number from string in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to generate a unique number from string. The string is a combination of username and password. I would like to generate a unique number id (not string) from this combination. I first md5 the combination and then convert it to number. The number length needs to be 10. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why does it have to be numeric?  Use a db identity column value?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to build here?

Comment: Cause the third party service requires it to be number.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you can provide more details about the third-party you're trying to interface with, because this is a very odd request and it contains a fundamental flaw. You ask for the number to be **unique**, but you are allowing for only 10 decimal ("number id") digits, or ~10 billion possible values.

This sounds like an awful lot but it's really not. This gives you a hash of just over 33 bits. The simple hash collision probability calculator at http://davidjohnstone.net/pages/hash-collision-probability puts this at a 44% chance of a collision at just 100,000 entries. But that assumes full usage of all the available input characters. Since username and password combinations are almost always limited to alphabetic and numeric characters, the real collision chance is much worse at far fewer entries (can't be calculated without knowing the characters you allow for these fields - but it's bad).

NodeJS provides numerous crypto functions in the `crypto` module. A whole set of hashing functions is available, including the ideal-case SHA* options. These can be used to provide safe, irreversible hashes with astronomically collision probabilities.

If these options are not usable for you, I would suggest you have a fundamental design flaw. You're almost certainly mapping a user/pass combination to a userID in a remote system in a way that an attacker would find easy to compromise with a simple brute-force attack, given the high collision risk in your model.

If you are doing what I think you are doing, the "right" way to do this would be to have a simple database on a server somewhere. The user/pass would be assigned a unique ID in there, and it doesn't matter what this is - it could be an auto-increment ID field in a single MySQL table. The server would then contact this remote service with the ID value for any API calls necessary, and return the results to the user. This eliminates the security risk because the username/password are not actually hashed, just stored, and can be checked 100% on every call.

Never use a hash as a primary data value. It's a simplification, not a real value on its own.